# Ways to Distinguish Retail from Wholesale Traffic in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, volusion

How can I implement tracking retail traffic vs wholesale traffic in Google Analytics on a shopping cart platform (e.g. Volusion)?

Comment: @Andy Tried re-wording the question. Is that better, or suggestions on wording?

Answer (score 0):

That question has more to do with, how can tell a retail from a wholesale?
Is there a specific page or hostname for each?

I'd suggest creating a custom segments based on page...

```
Name: Retail
Filter Visits Include
page contains retail.php AND
page does not contain retail.php

Name: Wholesale
Filter Visits Include
page contains wholesale.php AND
page does not contain retail.php

Name: Ambiguous
Filter Visits Include
page contains wholesale.php AND
page contains retail.php
```

The same could be done for wholesale, or landing page.

If the cart is opensource, under your control, and/or has an API you could also accomplish this with a user defined value OR a custom variable. If the cart supports Google Analytics eCommerce you could also do segments based on SKU numbers.

You need to give more detail about the structure of the site and where your wholesale and retail product pages live, if you want a more direct answer.

Comment: In this case it would be based on login. Logged in customers who are wholesale customers see different prices and have different shipping options. I guess I would need both a user level and a session level variable?